# change bootstrap class conditionally on DIV

Tags: angular, class, switch-statement

In my angular 4 app, I have a div which displays a message. This message should use class `alert alert-success` or `alert alert-danger` based on message shown. How I can I use one message and switch the class names.

```
<div class="alert alert-success" *ngIf="message.length > 0" >                                        
   <strong role="alert">{{message}}</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: switch the class names based on what? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ngClass`binding

```
  <div [ngClass]="message.length > 0? 'alert  alert-success' : 'alert  alert-danger'">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use ngClass. Use following code:

```
<div class="alert" [ngClass]="{'alert-success': expression, 'alert-success': expression}"></div>
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class1': true, 'class2': true, 'class3': false}">...</div>
```

OR

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class1 class2': true}">...</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response and i will try and update which I used

Comment: @user7000, Sure try it out both :)

Comment: @santosh, your solution worked for me. may be other solutions are similar they may also work